# General solution $\Delta^2y_t+2\Delta y_t=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following equation: $\Delta^2y_t+2\Delta y_t=0$ and want to transform it in such a way to derive the explicit formula for $y_t$.

Rewriting the delta as

$\Delta^2y_t+2\Delta y_t=(y_{t+1}-y_t)^2+2(y_{t+1}-y_t)=0$ Solving explicitly for $y_{t+1}$ gives me (pq formula) two solutions

1) $y_{t+1}=2-y_t$

2) $y_{t+1}=-y_t$

Which one is the "correct" one?

Comment: Maybe I am off base, but shouldn't the squared term give you a second order relation? Not a first order which is then squared?

Comment: it gives $y_{t+1}=y_t-2$ and $y_{t+1}=y_t=constant$.